# Why won't a custom app icon work for me even though I use the recommended code?

Tags: javascript, css, electron

I have a file in the same directory that is named icon.ico. I want the app to show that icon on the taskbar. Below is where I have tried putting the code to add the icon.

```
console.log(process.type)
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        frame: false,
        backgroundColor: '#008080',
        opacity: 0.7,
   })
```

I have tried looking on stackoverflow and youtube, and the two options I keep getting are

```
icon: __dirname + '/icon.ico',
```

and

```
icon: './pathto/desired/icon/icon.png'
```

People in the comments say that it works, but for me it doesn't. I can't think of any further information that I can provide, as it just wont work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as path from 'path'

icon: path.join(__dirname, '../../favicon.ico')
```

Comment: Got it! thanks. I actually did have the right code, my image was just corrupted